# Curl request fails error "Failed to connect to 103.xx.xxx.xx port 8085: Connection refused"

Tags: curl, port

$url = 'http://103.xx.xxx.xx:8085/MessagingGateway/SendTransSMS?Username='.$smsUserName.'&Password='.$smsUserPass.'&MessageType=txt&Mobile='.$mobile.'&SenderID='.$senderID.'&Message='.$message;

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);       
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $error = curl_error($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return response()->json(['status'=>'success', 'msg'=>$result, 'url' =>$url]);
```

Same code is working on localhost xampp server but it is not working godaddy shared hosting.

Error showing: "Failed to connect to 103.xx.xxx.xx port 8085: Connection refused". Please suggest me what i am doing wrong?

Comment: You're asking curl to connect to an IP address and TCP port where nothing is listening...

Answer (score 0):

Check if curl is enabled
Or you can enable it from php.ini file

If you have shared hosting, then may need to call hosting provider.

Comment: curl is enabled on server. 
cURL support enabled
cURL Information 7.36.0
Age 3

Answer (score 0):

It might help troubleshoot the issue if you could try to execute the same request from an https enabled domain/hosting. Additionally this might be related to your server's firewall blocking the request.